# Disproving uniform convergence of $e^{-nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I have proved that the following function sequence is pointwise convergence with the limit function

\begin{cases} 
      1 & x= 0 \\
      0 &  x\in  (0,1] 
   \end{cases}

where $f_{n}: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ and $f_{n}(x)=e^{-nx}$

In order to disprove uniform convergence I chose the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n}$ which converges to $0$ and did the following:

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{e}$ and let $N \in \mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Select $n = N$ as well as $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$. (Question, am I allowed to use $x$ as a sequence $x_{n}$ to disprove the sequence or does my $x$ have to be 'static', as in $x=\frac{1}{n}$)

$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=|e^{-n(\frac{1}{n})}-0|>=\frac{1}{e}$

Is this a correct way to disprove uniform convergence?

Comment: yes, you're right

Comment: Yes. More generally, if a sequence of continuous functions $\displaystyle \left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to a function that has a discontinuity, then the convergence cannot be uniform.